# How to get TRUE column position in wxStyledTextCtrl?

Tags: wxwidgets, wxstyledtextctrl

I have a `wxStyledTextCtrl` and I want to find the column number of a given position in the document. Basically I want a function like `GetColumn` but I don't want tabs to be expanded.

Does such a function exist?

Comment: What's with adding the Python tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PositionToXY()` method (inherited from the base class) to get this, at least with 2.9.4 it should give you what you need. If you use 2.8 and it doesn't work for you, you should do `line = LineFromPosition(pos)` and then use `pos - PositionFromLine(line)` as the index in this line.